# visual c# draw graphics in front of buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, button, graphics

I'm working on a winform project (visual c#). One of the forms has many buttons on it and they are located next to each other. I want to add graphics in front of those buttons, in a way the user could keep pressing the buttons. I can't add the graphics behind because the buttons hide the graphics and I don't want to move the buttons. I tried to bring the controls to the back but it didn't work. Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
toPolygon.Insert(toPolygon.Count, button); //insert button to vector
System.Drawing.Pen myPen;
myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
myPen.Width = 10;
System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, toPolygon[toPolygon.Count - 2].Location.X, toPolygon[toPolygon.Count - 2].Location.Y,
    button.Location.X , button.Location.Y); //draw a line from last button in the vector to the new one
myPen.Dispose();
if (toPolygon.First() == toPolygon.Last())
{   
    //draw polygon and clean the vector
}
```

Comment: so correct me if I'm wrong, but if the graphic is "in front" of the buttons, the user will not be able to see the buttons?!?

Comment: Can you show your code, please?

Comment: What is wrong with Button.Image or with the Paint event?

Comment: Basically you are right but it's still serves my needs. I'm only going to draw a polygon with thin "pen".

Comment: Can you not put images on the buttons using the Image property or the paint event of the button, like taffer already proposed ? Or is what you want a button that looks like an image ? In that case, can you not use image controls with an onclick event ?  It is just not clear at all what you are trying to do here

Comment: I just added the relevant part of my code in the original question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 things here, you can do what GuidoG said and make the button image the image you are trying to put over the button or in your form Designer if you click on your button and change it's BackColor to transparent by going to the "Web" tab and then change the "FlatSytle" to be "Flat" and then change the "ForeColor" to be transparent too. That way you will not see the button at all and be able to see everything behind it and still use it as a control.

And if you are trying to draw like lines over the control ect. you will have to overload the "OnPaint" method for that control.

Hope it helps!